# Anyone know whats wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Anyone able to see whats wrong with this code? Is going to be a ticker code so when a button is clicked 1 is added and then again 1 is going to change to 2 and so on and on basically its a clicker that when closed will remember the number it was on.

To be more clear these lines are coming up as errors:

```
countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              mCount++;
              countTextView.setTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
```

All of the code:

```
  package com.example.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // Private member field to keep track of the count
    private static int mCount = 0;

    private TextView countTextView;
    private Button countButton;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
    private SharedPreferences settings = null;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

    /** ADD THIS METHOD **/
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
      countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

      countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
              mCount++;
              countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
              editor = settings.edit(); 
              editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
              editor.commit();
          }
      });
    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


     }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();  
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();  
      mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
      countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
    }
    }
```

Comment: *...whats wrong with this code*: you should tell us what this code does, not only what it *should do*...

Comment: There appear to be a few things wrong with this code, but in terms of persisting the "mCount" state I think you have what onPause and onResume need to do backwards (in other words, do the PUT in onPause and the GET in onResume).

Comment: I get a "too localized" vibe from this question.  Off the cuff, I can't say what's wrong with this code - you would have to tell us what you're expecting and why it's not coming back the way you expect it to.

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BCw8tpvCIAAV7Wa.png when the button is clicked after the hello world te number one should come up then 2 when pressed again then so on

Comment: And like thkala asked, what *does* it do now?

Comment: these lines are coming up in red  countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View v) {

Comment: And what does it say when you click/hover over the error? It should tell you why it red-lined it.

Comment: it says this when hovered over the on click: The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)

Comment: You've imported the wrong `OnClickListener` then. import `View.OnClickListener` instead

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU ALL!!!! IT WORKS thanks to all of you that helped me get this to work! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have switched the logic between resume and pause.

Pause should persist your number.

Resume should read the old number.

Comment: I dont get you :L any chance you could edit it and re post on here?

Comment: Do your PUT in onPause and your GET in onResume, as I said above.

Comment: This would only break the counter on pause/resume or reorientation. Are the requirements so rigid?

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU ALL!!!! IT WORKS thanks to all of you that helped me get this to work! :D

Answer (score 1):

change     `new OnClickListener()` to `new View.OnClickListener()` in addition to what everyone suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `.setTextView.setText(..)` but simply use `.setText (CharSequence text)`.

Comment: ok cheers thats now left it till the onclicklisteners beings errors :) any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See the Following Running Code For your requirement

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// Private member field to keep track of the count
private static int mCount = 0;

private TextView countTextView;
private Button countButton;
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.example.myApp.mCount";
private SharedPreferences settings = null;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor = null;

/** ADD THIS METHOD **/
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
  countButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonCount);

  countButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
          mCount++;
          countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
          editor = settings.edit(); 
          editor.putInt("mCount", mCount);
          editor.commit();
      }
  });
settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);


 }

@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();  
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
  super.onResume();  
  mCount = settings.getInt("mCount", 0);
  countTextView.setText("Count: " + mCount);
}
}
```

Just Copy And Paste it. thats it.

Comment: the on click stuff is still getting an error

Comment: No it is impossible it is running fine on my machine just replace above code with your activity... thats it. than say again...

Comment: it says this when hovered over the on click: The type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick(DialogInterface, int)

Comment: OMG I LOVE YOU ALL!!!! IT WORKS thanks to all of you that helped me get this to work! :D

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
```

should be changed to

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

You're importing the wrong listener, so it's expecting a different method signature for `onClick()`

In addition to all the other things mentioned.